# ASRock onboard audio hardware not detected

Tags: windows-10, bios, motherboard

Got used computer from friend, cannot install new hardware in windows device manager. I am trying to install ALC662 which is the onboard audio hardware.

- Onboard HD Audio is set to enabled in BIOS
- device manager - add legacy hardware - no new hardware detected
- device manager - no audio device visible at all
- dxdiag shows no audio devices installed
  [image]
- old driver (after making invisible device visible)
  [image]

This is the mainboard ASRock N68-GS4/USB3 FX (Rev 1.0) BIOS v1.10
https://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68-GS4USB3%20FX

also tried linux - no audio hardware available. anyone can confirm this is hardware failure?

- [dmesg](https://pastebin.com/dXu72xiM)
- [lshw](https://pastebin.com/4zKDE2Fu)
- [lspci](https://pastebin.com/CqYXfPSe)
- [lsusb](https://pastebin.com/9vnfwg5K)
  Note: 0bda:8153 Realtek is external usb ethernet. on-board eth also not working (`forcedeth` no link although hardware **works in windows**)
- `mcelog` not available (even after `modprobe edac_mce_amd`)

  ```
  mcelog: ERROR: AMD Processor family 21: mcelog does not support this processor.
  ```

This is first time I get Windows 10 in my hands, it was installed already on this PC and I don't know how this was done. <s>I cannot find any chipset drivers for this mainboard</s>* although in device manager everything looks installed fine.
**just installed SMU-Driver NVIDIA all in 1 driver v15.37 for Windows 7*

Side note: ATI Radeon 5850 PCIe graphics card only black screen and not visible in device manager, maybe graphics card is broken now (it worked up to the removal from previous computer). I got onboard graphic working with 309.08 whql drivers, so just mention that because it may related to audio issue.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: You have not indicated what hardware you installed but wasn't detected. You have fairly old Nvidia drivers (more than 6 years old).

Comment: Thx I have updated question. The hardware not detected (onboard audio) is mentioned in headline + linked specs, but I have clarified that. AFAIK that is the last working driver for that graphics card NVIDIA GeForce 7025 for windows 10, but I think it's unrelated

Comment: 1)have you tried to reset BIOS by chance there is another settings we don't know could be causing? 2)Can you post a picture of BIOS, Device manager, & msinfo32 component sound section?

Comment: yes I reset BIOS previously. this is [msinfo32](https://pastebin.com/ZsGqusaW) not sure it is of any use as it is all german. will add photo from BIOS

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDdKg.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pqdV.jpg

Comment: msinfo32 *sound section* is empty. but in section *hardware - conflicts/shared ressources* I can see *NVIDIA nForce Serial ATA-Controller* and *High Definition Audio-Controller* sharing same IRQ, is that a conflict?

Comment: I think I recall nforce chipset c. 2013 (copyright in manual says c. 2013) did NOT play well with linux, so the linux emits may not be productive.

Comment: @Yorik and also Windows 10 no drivers (although Windows 10 mentioned in Windows 8.1 VGA drivers) I guess it's some ressources conflict or bad memory, haven't figured out yet

Comment: @gregg another mainboard, similar problem. There they claim malfunctioning BIOS update on manufacturer. Maybe I should buy BIOS chip with older version? https://www.reddit.com/r/gigabyte/comments/nt8wyf/missing_onboard_audio_device

Comment: @alecxs it's possible its a BIOS fault. I've never seen a BIOS chip replacement, I doubt in most instances its possible & it may cause more issues than it solves if you don't understand it fully. I see BIOS v1.30 is available you could TRY to update to see if it helps

Comment: https://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68-GS4%20FX/index.asp#BIOS

Comment: @gregg will try, although that is not exactly targeting right mainboard (no usb 3)

Comment: @alecxs indeed your variation only shows v1.10 you already have, sorry about that oversight I thought it was odd why you asked for this when it was easy to find:
[N68-GS4/USB3 FX](https://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68-GS4USB3%20FX/index.asp#BIOS)
[_N68-GS4/USB3 FX R2.0_](https://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68-GS4USB3%20FX%20R2.0/index.asp#BIOS)

Comment: @gregg tried v1.00 no luck, only difference increased system boot time. Also tried other RAM and PSU. Noticed more errors like [crc errors](https://superuser.com/q/1286114) on disk and some video glitches. I guess the mainboard is simply toast

Comment: @gregg might be the reason that AMD FX CPU requires Sockel AM3+ but this mainboard is only AM3 - finally replaced the mainboard itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [pg43 manual notes](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/N68-GS4%20FX.pdf):

> Onboard HD Audio Select [Auto], [Enabled] or [Disabled] for the
> onboard HD Audio feature. **If you select [Auto], the onboard HD Audio
> will be disabled when PCI Sound Card is plugged**

- [Someone also mentioned no audio after installing new GFX card](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/audio-not-working-after-installing-a-new-graphics-card.447654/)

  - I assume there is no graphics card installed per your notes. However you note an ATI one was possibly used, if you ever got it working the drivers could still be installed causing the above condition.
  - [Might want to go through the Audio FAQ's on asrock's website](https://www.asrock.com/support/faq.asp?c=Audio)
- It's possible the [Win8 drivers on asrock website](https://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68-GS4%20FX/index.asp#Download) [may not work under Win10](https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/245275-windows-10-just-formatted-problem-with-audio-and-nvidia-drivers-help/). However it appears this [alc662 has a Win10 driver as seen on Lenovo](https://support.lenovo.com/hr/en/downloads/ds104333) so a driver IS available/compatible
- Can you uninstall all the audio devices? I suspect one is possibly overriding the built-in one. *You have a iPhone, JBL, Microsoft Proxy/Streaming, Phillips, USB, Wireless Controller*
- Could be worth resetting CMOS. Refer to [pg18 in manual](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/N68-GS4%20FX.pdf)
- I don't know much about Linux, but I have had various wireless & audio issues many times that eventually get fixed with some configuration change so it not working that could simply be complexities/particularities of Linux. Your `lshw` shows a `Nvidia MCP61` audio device. The `lspci` indicates the `MCP61` is actually the chipset that in turn talks to the audio controller